# Gradle exception while integrating srtipe in flutter app

Tags: android-studio, gradle, flutter, dart, stripe-payments

I am working in a flutter app with firebase already integrated.

When I added the flutter package for stripe and run the app i get gradle exception.

App build.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.lab.murtuza.qualvet"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.0.1'

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version (e.g. "[1.3.1
  ,2.3]", but isn't being resolved to that version. Behavior exhibited by the library will be unknown.

```
Dependency failing: com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt:7.7 -> net.minidev:json-smart@[1.3.1,2.3], but json-smart version was 2
  .3.

  The following dependencies are project dependencies that are direct or have transitive dependencies that lead to the art
  ifact with the issue.

  -- Project 'app' depends on project 'stripe_payment' which depends onto com.stripe:stripe-android@10.3.1
  -- Project 'app' depends onto net.minidev:json-smart@2.3
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.stripe:stripe-3ds2-android@1.2.1
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt@7.7
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.stripe:stripe-android@10.3.1
```

For extended debugging info execute Gradle from the command line with ./gradlew --info :app:assembleDebug to see the dep
  endency paths to the artifact. This error message came from the google-services Gradle plugin, report issues at https://
  github.com/google/play-services-plugins and disable by adding "googleServices { disableVersionCheck = false }" to your b
  uild.gradle file.

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  countdown: ^0.1.0
  stripe_payment: ^0.2.1
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.3+4
  google_maps_flutter: ^0.5.21
  image: ^2.1.4
  flutter_lorem: ^1.1.0
  geoflutterfire: ^2.0.3+5
  firebase_core: ^0.4.0+1
  cloud_firestore: ^0.12.9+3
  firebase_storage: ^3.0.6
  firebase_auth: ^0.14.0+5
  fluttertoast: ^3.1.3
  location: ^2.3.5
  flutter_spinkit: "^4.0.0"
  image_picker: ^0.6.1+4

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

Please help me fix this bug.

Comment: Please, paste also your `pubspec.yaml` dependencies

Comment: Added, pls have a look

Comment: What was your eventual solution to this problem?
I am running into this right now

Answer (score 0):

I think, there is nothing in that failure that depends of `gradle`. All this dependencies are in your `pubspec` file, as you can see in logs.

First thing you can try to do - check all of these dependencies here https://pub.dev/ and set them latest versions.

If this won't help - I can't give you 100% solution. When I faced such problem - I just tried to downgrade version of conflicting dependency and tried to rebuild project (all previous versions you can see at the same site https://pub.dev/).

Actually, I don't see `com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt` dependency in `pubspec`, so it must be in `gradle` file but not in yours. Some of your `pubspec` dependency contains native code.

You can explore your dependencies by looking on the left of Android studio - in the tree there is in `External libraries` -> `Flutter plugins`

Comment: Oh okay, i will try and let you know. Thank you